# Omitting parentheses in cond leads to strange result

Tags: scheme

Consider the following snippet

```
(define (f a b c)    
   (
     cond ((and (< b c) (< b a)) (+ c  a))
          ((and (< a c) (< a b)) (+ c b))
          ((and (< c b) (< c a)) (+ b  a))
   ) 
)

(display (f 2 1 3)) ; 5
(newline)
(display (f 2 8 3)) ; 11
(newline)
(display (f 2 8 -3)) ; 10
```

Now if I comment the second line and second line from bottom

```
(define (f a b c)    
   ;(
     cond ((and (< b c) (< b a)) (+ c  a))
          ((and (< a c) (< a b)) (+ c b))
          ((and (< c b) (< c a)) (+ b  a))
   ;) 
)
```

The result is

```
#<undef>
11
10
```

I could not explain why omitting the parentheses lead to that result. In the second case, I expected thtat the complier would treat `cond ((and (< b c) (< b a)) (+ c  a))`, `((and (< a c) (< a b)) (+ c b))` and `((and (< a c) (< a b)) (+ c b))` as three expressions, the latter two invalid, instead it seems they got executed.

Comment: We don't know what Scheme version you're running, but mine throws an error, that lonely `cond` without brackets results in an immediate `cond: bad syntax in: cond` error.

Comment: I used the one in [Repl.it](https://repl.it) called `BiwaScheme Interpreter version 0.6.4`. Thank you, now that it does not seem to be a good Scheme interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `cond` keyword should raise an exception when it's interpreted.

But, if your interpreter does not throw any error, you are in the case of block statement, in which the evaluation of the last expression provides the result, the other ones are computed only for side-effects.  The code reduces to this:

```
(define (f a b c)  ((and (< c b) (< c a)) (+ b  a))))
```

Comment: And that's never valid code, since `(and (< ...) (< ...))` is `#t` or `#f`, not a function.

Comment: @tfb (and ...) is all the time boolean? No, you are not in #C here...

Comment: @allinsure `(and ...)` may not be a boolean, but `(and (< ...) (< ...))` is, because `(< ...)` always returns a boolean.  Which is why I specified that in my comment.  I have no idea what the rules are in C.

Comment: @tfb ((and (< c b) (< c a)) (+ b  a)) means apply #t or #f on (+ b a) which is an error, yes.  I thing OP did not really inform correctly about the code he wrote and the interpreter used, but this is other issue...